# Mongoose not fetching data in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

No data is fetched while using mongoshell, it is working fine

server.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const topicRoute = require('./routes/topicRoute')

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

const dbUri = "mongodb+srv://rohan:password@db_name.qg229.mongodb.net/db_name"
mongoose.connect(dbUri)

app.use("/",topicRoute)

app.listen(3001,function(){
    console.log("Server started")
})
```

routes/topicRoute.js file, no error is catched here & object Object is returned

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Topic = require('../models/topicModel')

router.route("/topics").get((req,res)=>{
    Topic.find().then(fetchedTopics => res.json(fetchedTopics))
})
module.exports = router
```

models/topicModel.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const topicSchema = {
    topic_id: String,
    topic_name: String,
    topic_description: String,
}

const Topic = mongoose.model('topics',topicSchema)

module.exports = Topic
```

Comment: Is the cred correct? You are getting object Object because you need to use two then clause `then(res=>res.json()).then(res => ())`

Comment: Still not working, applied res.json()

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code for database connection

```
// database connection 
const { MongoClient, Collection } = require('mongodb');
    
    const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017' const database = 'ecom'     // database name define here const collectionName = 'reviews';   //database collection define here const client = new MongoClient(url);
    
    async function getData(){
        let result =await client.connect();
        let db = result.db(database)
        let collection = db.collection(collectionName)
        let response = await collection.find({}).toArray()
        console.log(response); }
    
    getData();
```

Comment: Still Not working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).